# Android - Does MediaMuxer support WebM now?

Tags: android, output, webm, mediamuxer

The Documentation states the following:

> MediaMuxer facilitates muxing elementary streams. Currently **only supports an mp4 file as the output** and at most one audio and/or one video elementary stream.

When I look up the MediaMuxer.OutputFormat packages there's also an "MUXER_OUTPUT_WEBM" constant. Is it only a placeholder or does the MediaMuxer already support webM for muxing audio and video data? If not, is there currently a way to muxing into a webM-container?

Comment: Looks like it was added in API 21. I don't know what it'll do, but if you take a simple project (e.g. Grafika, https://github.com/google/grafika) and change the constant in one of the activities you should be able to evaluate whether or not the output is what you need.